# An embarassing question about photon power, Hamiltonians, and converting units

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resonance, magnetic-moment, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

I am a hapless experimentalist, and desperate for a bit of advice.

I am trying to do a spin-density calculation building on some of the ideas contained in [this paper](https://dx.doi.org/10.1039/C2CP23233B). In brief, it's describing a magnetic resonance experiment with both electrons and nuclei in a magnetic field, subject to either radiofrequency or microwave irradiation -- [dynamic nuclear polarization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_nuclear_polarization). The relevant equation to be solved in order to determine the dynamics of what happens is the Liouville-von-Neumann equation, and it contains a Hamiltonian that is a sum of many terms. Most of these I understand quite well.

The one part I do not get is the term that represents the effect of a constant, continuous-wave microwave (MW) irradiation. The relevant hamiltonian is simple -- it is

$$
H_\text{irr}=\frac{\omega_1}{2}\left(\hat{S}_+ +\hat{S}_-\right).
$$

The term $\omega_1$, is described as the "microwave power" in [the code](https://spindynamics.org/wiki/index.php?title=Dnp_time_dep.m) corresponding to these simulations, as the "strength of the mw irradiation field" in the paper. In the experiments that corresponds to this, on which I work, microwave power is a very real thing measured in Watts that I naïvely expect to correspond to the mod-square of the E field inside a sample chamber. It both affects the nuclear polarization obtained, the degree of partial saturation of electronic spins, and the heating of the sample chamber (which is held at a few kelvin)

- Hamiltonians have units of energy
- $\omega_1$ has units of radians per second
- Different conventions exist for the spin operator, $\hat{S}_\pm$, but typically they contain a factor of $\hbar$ and therefore have units of J$\cdot$s / rad.
- So it is entirely "obvious" that $\omega_1$ correctly has units of radians per second.

Therefore, $\omega_1$ is a proper frequency. In other areas of MR, we are loose about units and convert e.g. volts in a probe/coil into an effective $B_1$-field by Maxwell's equations, and then obtain a flip angle by multiplying with the gyromagnetic ratio for the nucleus in question. All of this is relatively well understood.

I want to know what $\omega_1$ corresponds to in "lab units". This convention isn't unique to this paper either; [others](https://spindynamics.org/wiki/index.php?title=Dnp_time_dep.m) describe it as "a MW irradiation Hamiltonian $H=\omega_1 \sum_\ell \hat{S}_{x,\ell}$ is added [...] where $\omega_1$ is the irradiation intensity"; or [alternatively](https://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jmr.2013.10.025) as "where $2\omega_1$ is the MW irradiation strength in the laboratory frame". The latter is particularly useful as they provide both experimental data and a value for $\omega_1$: 144 MHz around an electron Larmor frequency of 95 GHz. This is *tiny* in comparison. Typically we have a few tens to hundreds of mW of microwave power for an experiment like that is described. Although that paper is about a frequency swept scheme, it is still the case that the nutation frequency is *different* again.

My questions are thus.

1. What the hell *actually is* $\omega_1$? It's not related to the mod-square-of-the-E-field, is it? If there is, there's an implicit factor of $g$ (edit: or $\gamma=g\mu/\hbar$) in there, isn't there?
2. I realise I am woefully ignorant of how the strength of a photon irradiation field comes into a Hamiltonian. I'm used to there being a spectral density function if required and some other terms that ultimately come out in the wash with Fermi's golden rule.
3. Although this clearly is a standard nomenclature, I don't appear to recognise it -- I don't think it's in Abragam's big book of magnetic resonance, for example. What's a good way to (minimally painfully) work out how to map my experimental system's parameters onto this one?

Any and all pointers gratefully received. I have spent much of the last week obsessed with this particular problem as I should be able to reproduce some experimental results relatively quickly.

Comment: They seem to have stripped the magnetic moment out of these formulas. It's not spins that are interacting with microwave frequencies but magnetic moments that are interacting with magnetic fields. One can chose units so that for a given spin species (electrons, protons, other nuclei with non-zero magnetic moment etc.) the formula simplifies to the above. Is it good software practice? Probably not. Physicists are sloppy when it comes to writing code.

Comment: @FlatterMann Very true. That's what I alluded to with $g$ in there (which is used by convention for electrons; $\gamma=g\mu/\hbar$ for nuclei). I'm just more deeply unhappy with the fact that it's universally referred to as a power or "strength" which to me is dimensionally inconsistent any which way you look at it. 

Much like in particle physics, I suspect there's a convenient convention where $c=\hbar=\cdots=1$ and I just happen to be unaware of it.

Comment: I don't think your question is about physics as much as it is about notation. I assume that the person who wrote this code got the formula from one of the standard textbooks in which a theorist has done the theorist thing, which is to strip all the non-essential physics out of the formulas. The absolute strength of the magnetic field is non-essential physics, after all. It is determined by the shape of the magnetic resonance coils, which are just some random assemblies of copper wire and the local magnetic properties of the material. These are irrelevant.

Comment: You're quite right – it's not _essential_ to the physics of the problem; but it is _essential_ to the experiment! A bit later on and I'm increasingly convinced that the thing I'm missing is that it is (I think) a Rabi oscillation, which occurs at a frequency $\Omega =\frac{g \mu_0 \mu_b}{\hbar} \left\langle  a | J | b \right\rangle |\mathbf{H}|$ where the matrix element is for the transition involved (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4745747). I guess under the assumption that $\Omega=\omega_1$ this is something I can probably make a guess at..

Comment: That sounds about right. I do agree, by the way, that it's probably not good practice to write software like that. The documentation about where this came from is insufficient. What would happen if we did this "right", though, and we included the magnetic field in the code? Now the user would be required to enter an unknown quantity that is very hard to calculate and nearly impossible to measure with the required precision... other than with the resonance experiment itself. In the data analysis it turns into an otherwise meaningless fitting parameter.